# Rails app for an existing database which does not use Rails naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, naming-conventions, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I would like to write a Rails app for an existing database written for a Java web app. The primary key is not the autoincrementing "id" column expected by ActiveRecord, but a multipart key based on two specific attributes. Also, the foreign key is not named using Rails conventions, but there is a foreign key statement referring that field to a field in another table. I would like this to work with Rails model methods such as :has_many and :belongs_to.

Is there an automagic tool which can read an existing schema and generate an ActiveRecord model based on that schema (especially one as I have described) or do I have to do everything by hand?

Answer (score 0):

there is no silver bullet, but there is some things can help you to use legacy DB:

1. [composite_primary_keys](https://github.com/drnic/composite_primary_keys) - Composite Primary Keys support for Active Record
2. foreign_key can be specified as an option in association, see [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)
3. autoincrement can be added via callback before_create or new db column that will be better